# Given an array $A$ and an index $c$, prove there always exists a subarray whose sum $\pmod {i} = 0$

Tags: proof-assistants

> Given an array $A$ of positive integers with size $m$ and an array index $c$ (indexing starts at $1$). Prove using mathematical induction over $m$ that there always exists a contiguous subarray $S$ in $A$ such that the (sum of the elements of $S$) $\pmod {i} = 0.$

I'm unable to find the correct approach to solve this. I'm sure the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) will be useful here, but I don't know how to correctly apply it within the proof. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to do it, no induction involved.

Suppose you augment your initial list $A = [a_1, a_2, ..., a_m]$ with a new element at the beginning $a_0 = 0$, $A' = [a_0, a_1, ..., a_m]$.

Now build partial sums of $A'$, such that $P_i = \sum_0^i a_j$. Notice that the sums of elements in the initial list from positions $b$ to position $e$ is $\sum_b^e a_i = P_e - P_{b - 1}$. Notice $P_0 = 0$ is defined since we added $a_0$. This is a very common trick when you care about the sums of intervals.

Back to the problem, you need to proof there exist two index $i < j$ such that $c | (P_j - P_i)$. This is equivalent to say that there exist two index $i < j$ such that $P_i \equiv P_j \mod c$. We only care about remainder of each element in $P$ if they are divided by $c$, and moreover we should only show that at least two elements have the same remainder.

Now notice the number of different remainders given $c$ is at most $c$ and the length of the list $P$ is $|P| = m + 1$. Since $c \le m < |P|$ by the Pigeonhole principle you can guarantee at least two elements in $P$ have the same remainder.

Comment: Thanks, this is maybe a more elegant way to do it, however the question is specifically asking for an inductive proof.

Comment: Ok, I respect that, but in this particular problem induction doesn't really seems to help in any way, since the arguments in the demonstration without induction are exactly the same as in the demonstration with induction. It just increase the length of the demonstration and in some sense its complexity IMO.

Comment: "by the Pigeonhole principle you can guarantee at least two elements in $P$ have the same remainder". Does this still hold if we know that we will never use $P_0$ (as every donation $a_i \geq 1$?) Wouldn't we then have exactly $m$ elements in $P$?

Comment: @iMazing Remember, $P_i$ are used to represent sums on the intervals: the $a_i \geq 1$ condition does not apply. We have restated the problem in terms of $P$ using this formula $\sum_b^e a_i = P_e - P_{b-1}$. And we, also, are searching for $i$ and $j$ that are _not_ equal, this time, to preserve "one-to-one mapping" between the problems. (Additionally, we _use_ $P_0$ by allowing $i$ to be at least 1.)

Answer (score 1):

Let `P(m)` denote the statement we are trying to prove: Given a positive-integer array `A` of size `m` and a `c` in `[m]` there is a (contiguous) subarray whose sum modulo `c` is 0.

Let us say that such subarrays `satisfy` P(m).

P(1) is trivial since c = 1.

Assume P(m). Let's try to prove for P(m+1).

If `c <= m`, then ignore the last element of the array and notice that any subarray that satisfies P(m) also satisfies P(m+1).

Assume `c == m+1`.

Consider the `m+1` sums:
`S1 = A[1]%(m+1), S2 = (A[1] + A[2])%(m+1),.... S_(m+1) = (A[1] + A[2] + ... + A[m+1])%(m+1)`

If one of the `S_i == 0`, then, sub-array `A[1..i]` satisfies P(m+1).

If none of the `S_i` are 0, each `S_i` can only take on one of the `m` values in the range `{1,2,...,m}`. By Pigeonhole Principle, there must be indices `i < j` such that `S_i == S_j` and `A[i+1 ... j]` satisfies P(m+1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm having some trouble understanding the last argument (when none of the $S_i$'s "= 0". How can we be sure that each $S_i$ takes exactly one value in $[m]$? And if $S_i = S_j$, why does `A[i+1 ... j]` satisfy $P(m+1)$?

Comment: Because S_j = S_i + A[i+1] + A[i+2] + ... + A[j] (modulo m).